# What do I have to do after setting contentInset or automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets for it to actually beeing applied?

Tags: ios, ios7, uiscrollview, setneedsdisplay, insets

I have got an `UIViewController` containing an `UIScrollView`. Initially `automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets` is not set (so it should default to `YES`).

On some user interaction I set `automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets` to `NO`, so I can set my own `contentInset` on the scroll view.

After doing so nothing happens. What do I have to call afterwards?

Calling `setNeedsDisplay` on the scroll view doesn’t help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want your initial display of your scrollview to include an initial content offset, then set the contentInset value in `viewDidLoad`.
If you wish to dynamically change the contentInset and have the contentOffset change as well, then you need to adjust the contentOffset at the same time as the contentInset. For example:

```
// Adjust content inset and initial offset to account for the header
UIEdgeInsets contentInset = self.collectionView.contentInset;
contentInset.top += self.stickyHeaderView.bounds.size.height;
self.collectionView.contentInset = contentInset;
if (-1 * self.collectionView.contentOffset.y < contentInset.top) {
    CGPoint contentOffset = self.collectionView.contentOffset;
    contentOffset.y = -1*contentInset.top;
    [self.collectionView setContentOffset:contentOffset animated:YES];
}
```